# Jenkins publishConfluence: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, confluence

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/release-xxx returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:688)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:539)
at com.atlassian.confluence.rest.client.AbstractRemoteService.put(AbstractRemoteService.java:291)
Caused: com.atlassian.confluence.api.service.exceptions.InternalServerException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.atlassian.confluence.rest.client.model.ExceptionConverter$Client.convertToServiceException(ExceptionConverter.java:94)
at com.atlassian.confluence.rest.client.AbstractRemoteService.put(AbstractRemoteService.java:293)
at com.atlassian.confluence.rest.client.AbstractRemoteService.lambda$putFuture$8(AbstractRemoteService.java:136)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**As you can see, I get FAILURE results and 500 Internal Server Error, but the confluence page is updated. What is wrong here?
Jenkins Pipeline fails, but Confluence page Updated.**

Comment: An issue is open for this problem on Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69157?jql=resolution%20is%20EMPTY%20and%20component%3D15948